# How to add a loading page when i click the pagination in datatable plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I want to add a simple loading effect before the pagination link is clicked and closed the loading page after the table is redrawed. I tried serveral methods to do it, but the result is not quite OK. I even tried the jQuery.bind-first plugin. No effect. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

```
var idCredit = (parseInt($.getUrlVar('idCredit'))).toString();
            $("#idCredit").val(idCredit);
            var oTable =  $('#companyInfoConnectionGrid').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": false,   
        "sScrollX":"100%",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        //"sScrollY": 420,
        "bSort": true,
        "bDestroy":true,
        "iDisplayLength":10,
        //"aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource":"queryCompanyInfoCreditAssociation",
        "bSort": false,   
        "bServerSide":true,
        "bLengthChange":false, 
        "fnServerData":retrieveData,
        "fnDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
                        window.top.Comm.stopPageLoading();
            },
        //"sColumns":["id","productCode","name",connectionType,grantQuota,approvalAmount,status,result,reason,edate],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "id",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    var workflow = row.workflow=="" ? 0 : row.workflow;
                    var a = '<a href="javascript:this.parent.parent.queryAuditNavigate('+data+',' + workflow + ')">'+data+'</a>'
                    return a;
                }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "productCode",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "name",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "companyName",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "connectionType",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "grantQuota",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "approvalAmount",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "status"
            },
            { "mDataProp": "result",
                    render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                        if(""===data || null === data){
                            return "-"
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "reason",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { "mDataProp": "edate",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "overdueSign",
                render:function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    if(""===data || null === data){
                        return "-"
                    }
                    return data;
                } },
            { "mDataProp": "detail"
            }
        ]
        }
});

$("#companyInfoConnectionGrid_paginate").onFirst("click", "a", function() {
        debugger;
         window.top.Comm.startPageLoading();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bProcessing: true`.

From the [official documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features):

> `bProcessing`
>
> Enable or disable the display of a 'processing' indicator when the table is being processed (e.g. a sort). This is particularly useful for tables with large amounts of data where it can take a noticeable amount of time to sort the entries.

If you want to change default message, use [`oLanguage.sProcessing`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n) option :

```
"oLanguage": {
  "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy"
}
```